# Unable to "apportable load". Give NoneType error

Tags: ios, apportable

Trying to use apportable for the first time. Keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

and also

```
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
```

And then the script terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Background: This can occur if you've updated to Xcode 5. It seems Xcode 5 has a bug that it can generate incorrect output when running xcodebuild.

Comment: Great! Now I'm getting further and it's crashing with "ValueError: No closing quotation"
in

xcode.py:
framework = shlex.split(framework_cmd.strip())[1]

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. Could be caused a sub-project that has no sources. Removing that sub-project should allow the build system to scan the Xcode build properly. 2. spaces in a directory name. If neither, create another question showing more logging.

Comment: Hi, is there any update possible or workaround for xCode5 ? i just updated my dev tool ;( and getting this output.

Comment: Not yet. Hopefully, in the next few weeks.